# Flash Namespace error 1004: Namespace was not found or is not a compile-time constant

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, namespaces

I have a class: `myClass_x.as` with contents:

```
package com.a.b.c
{
    public namespace myClass_x = "com.a.b.c:myClass_x";
}
```

I have a second class: `myClass_y` with function:

`myClass_x function myFunction(param1:int, param2:int, param3:int) : void {...}`

I have a third class: `myClass_z` with function:

`override myClass_x function myFunction(param1:int, param2:int, param3:int) : void {...}`

When I try to compile, I get error:

`1004: Namespace was not found or is not a compile-time constant.`

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've imported the namespace at the top of each class?

```
import com.a.b.c.myClass_x;
```

You can also get your error if the filename does not exactly match the namespace name.

Comment: Yes, namespace is at the top of each class. The filename is

`myClass_x.cs`

and the namespace name is 

`public namespace myClass_x = "com.a.b.c:myClass_x";`

Comment: @gatzkerob Why is the file extension .cs? Did you mean .as?

Comment: Yes, I meant .as - Post has been edited to show change. Still trying to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Above your class block add the line `use namespace myClass_x;`